# JAI vendorname == null

Tags: java, jai

So I finished coding my application to rotate TIFF images which required JAI to manipulate the TIFFs.

It works fine when working under Eclipse, but whenever I build a fat jar for the library and then create one implementing that (per http://fjep.sourceforge.net/fjeptutorial.html), when I do the java -jar Push.jar \path\to\dir, it runs up until it hits the part where it is compressing and saving:

```
TIFFImageWriterSpi tiffspi = new TIFFImageWriterSpi();
ImageWriter writer = tiffspi.createWriterInstance();
//Iterator<ImageWriter> iter =  ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("TIFF");
//ImageWriter writer = iter.next();

ImageWriteParam param2 = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();
param2.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);

param2.setCompressionType("LZW");
param2.setCompressionQuality(0.0f);
File fOutputFile = workArea[i];
ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(fOutputFile);
writer.setOutput(ios);

if (frontPage == 1)
{
     writer.write(null, new IIOImage(pg1, null, null), param2);
     writer.writeInsert(-1, new IIOImage(pg2, null, null), param2);
}
else if (frontPage == 2)
{
     writer.write(null, new IIOImage(pg2, null, null), param2);
     writer.writeInsert(-1, new IIOImage(pg1, null, null), param2);
}

remaining = remaining - 1;
    if (remaining > 0)
     System.out.println(remaining + " remaining.");
else
     System.out.println("Done.");
```

It blows up on the first line of that section with the message:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName == null!
 ....rest of stack trace.
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since I spent a considerable amount of time debugging this problem, I thought I would share my solution here, despite the age of the question. Srikanth's second [link](http://www.java.net/node/695773) was particularly helpful.

### Reason for the error

JAI requires a vendor name for some of its deep internals, particularly the javax.imageio.spi.IIOServiceProvider which gets used by many (all?) of the image readers for their low-level IO. It's not picky what the string is, but it can't be null.

Rather than hard-code the vendor name, the ImageReaderSpi class gets the vendor name from sun.media.imageioimpl.common.PackageUtil.getVendor(). This in turn *reads it from the jar's MANIFEST.MF*. Normally you link against the standard jai-imageio packagage, so Sun's vendor info gets read. However, since you're making a fat jar file, you replaced Sun's MANIFEST.MF with your own which lacks the required information.

### Solution

Include the following lines in your MANIFEST.MF file:

```
Specification-Title: Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools
Specification-Version: 1.1
Specification-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Implementation-Title: com.sun.media.imageio
Implementation-Version: 1.1
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
```

The values for each property can be anything (I used my specific application/version/company), as long as all six are defined.

### Maven

If you were using maven's assembly plugin to create your fat jar, maven can automatically include the correct version numbers and such. Update your `pom.xml` with the following `<archive>` section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
            </manifest>
            <manifestEntries>
                <Specification-Vendor>MyCompany</Specification-Vendor>
                <Implementation-Vendor>MyCompany</Implementation-Vendor>
            </manifestEntries>
        </archive>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-my-bundle</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Better and more clear than "officially" accepted solution! Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps, but this answer didn't come until 2 years after a working solution was "officially" accepted. I am going to switch it to this one only because the 2nd link, the one that provided the solution as written here but without the explanation, seems to have had the link cannibalized so it isn't as helpful as it was at the time.

Comment: Maybe you can have a look at https://github.com/geoHeil/jai-packaging-problem it is not the same problem i.e. I checked the maifest entries, but something in the fat jar is null.

Answer (score 5):

I had to use this [ImageIO jar](http://forum.servoy.com/download/file.php?id=2342). It worked like a charm. Found it [here](http://forum.servoy.com/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=13625&p=70765#p70765).

Comment: Note: this imageio jar has been patched to use hardcoded strings to avoid the call to PackageUtil which tries to resolve vendorName from the manifest.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer by Quantum7 explains the source of the problem, and in the **Maven** section it provides a solution when using the Maven Assembly plugin to produce a JAR including dependencies. If you are instead using the Maven Shade plugin to produce the JAR with dependencies, the configuration is slightly different. You can add something like the following to the configuration section of the Shade plugin in your `pom.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <transformers>
        <transformer
                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
                <Main-Class>com.conveyal.r5.R5Main</Main-Class>
                <Specification-Title>Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools</Specification-Title>
                <Specification-Version>1.1</Specification-Version>
                <Specification-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Specification-Vendor>
                <Implementation-Title>com.sun.media.imageio</Implementation-Title>
                <Implementation-Version>1.1</Implementation-Version>
                <Implementation-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Implementation-Vendor>
                <Extension-Name>com.sun.media.imageio</Extension-Name>
            </manifestEntries>
        </transformer>
    </transformers>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

## DISCLAIMER

The issue that I was having was slightly different, I was getting the "ClassNotFound" error while trying to run a compiled jar file. I happened upon this SO question while researching, so for others who followed the same trail that I did, here you go.

#### Possible Solution to ClassNotFound Error

To those who may find this question later on, if nothing else seems to work, You could try using the [Apache Shader](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) plugin for Maven. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620281/what-is-the-maven-shade-plugin-used-for-and-why-would-you-want-to-relocate-java) is some more information on it.

I'm not experienced enough to be able to tell you **how** it does it, but Apache Shader packages all the used dependencies in your project into the final jar file, so that all the dependencies are included in the META-INF folder when it's built. This increases the size of the jar file (depending on how many libraries you used in your project), but also seems to fix the jar not being able to find classes from outside libraries that are used.

To use the Shader plugin, add the following to your POM. I included it after the dependencies tag and before the properties tag.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <manifestEntries>
                                    <Main-Class>com.package.name.className</Main-Class>
                                    <Build-Number>1</Build-Number>
                                </manifestEntries>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

***NOTE***: Make sure you change the package and class name to reflect your project's package and class names.

Other useful links: [Similar stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345769/exception-when-trying-to-save-images)

Answer (score 2):

(Would have been a comment on Quantum7's answer if I had enough reputation)

I ran into the same problem. Quantum7's answer saved the day! After putting in manifestEntries Specification-Vendor and Implementation-Vendor, however, the execution of my fat jar still failed with the exception below. Note it is

> version == null!

not

> vendorName == null!

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: version == null!
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIOServiceProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderWriterSpi.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi.<init>(CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        ... 14 more
```

Putting in manifestEntries below fixed it.

```
<manifestEntries>
    <Specification-Title>Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools</Specification-Title>
    <Specification-Version>1.1</Specification-Version>
    <Specification-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Specification-Vendor>
    <Implementation-Title>com.sun.media.imageio</Implementation-Title>
    <Implementation-Version>1.1</Implementation-Version>
    <Implementation-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Implementation-Vendor>
</manifestEntries>
```

When running the fat jar, I made sure that none of the three values in the code below is null.

```
import com.sun.media.imageioimpl.common.PackageUtil;

public class ManifestCheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(PackageUtil.getVendor());
        System.out.println(PackageUtil.getVersion());
        System.out.println(PackageUtil.getSpecificationTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: The 'addDefaultImplementationEntries' part of my maven configuration defines the title and version based on project properties. If you want to set them to Sun's info (which I don't recommend; customized entries work fine), then you should omit the <manifest> block.

Answer (score 1):

These can help you to solve the problem.

[How to run jai-imageio with source code](http://www.java.net/node/677168)

[vendorName == null](http://www.java.net/node/695773)

Comment: The bottom link worked. I removed the two non-Main Class sections of the manifest generated and put the JAI spec stuff in it at the top. Loaded fine after this when doing java -jar.

Comment: For others: this is essentially the thing better described in [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18495658/365237)

Comment: I've set the other answer to be the answer because the vendorName == null link that resolved the issue redirects to the community section of the site and searching for that string only returns a question with a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting the same error after struggling for many solution found this and worked for me.

Need to give venderName manually in code as:

```
import com.sun.media.imageioimpl.common.PackageUtil;

    
    try {
        MainClass.afVenderNames(PackageUtil.class, "afreen", "afreen", "afreen");
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SecurityException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(PackageUtil.getVendor());
    System.out.println(PackageUtil.getVersion());
    System.out.println(PackageUtil.getSpecificationTitle());
    
    
    
    public static void afVenderNames(Class<?> PackageUtil, String vendor, String version, String specTitle)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field vendorField = PackageUtil.getDeclaredField("vendor");
    vendorField.setAccessible(true);
    vendorField.set(null, vendor);

    Field versionField = PackageUtil.getDeclaredField("version");
    versionField.setAccessible(true);
    versionField.set(null, version);

    Field specTitleField = PackageUtil.getDeclaredField("specTitle");
    specTitleField.setAccessible(true);
    specTitleField.set(null, specTitle);
}
```

It doesn't matter what will be the vendorName value is if it's not NULL.
My code was running fine in eclipse but giving exceptions in an exported runnable jar.

Finally worked when wrote the above code and exported the jar.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and based on previous answers in here I constructed a configuration for the maven-shade-plugin that worked for me. I include it here as a template for others:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <manifestEntries>
              <Specification-Title>Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O Tools</Specification-Title>
              <Specification-Version>1.1</Specification-Version>
              <Specification-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Specification-Vendor>
              <Implementation-Title>com.sun.media.imageio</Implementation-Title>
              <Implementation-Version>1.1</Implementation-Version>
              <Implementation-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Implementation-Vendor>
            </manifestEntries>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
      </configuration>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>shade</goal>
          </goals>  
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```