# Java- export to jar- i/o problems

Tags: java, executable-jar, java-io, javax.imageio

I work on Eclipse (Juno with JDK7), and the program runs (on Eclipse) fine.
My problematic lines are:

```
URL imageURL = new URL("http://www.idautomation.com/ocr-a-and-ocr-b-fonts/new_sizes_ocr.png");   
RenderedImage img = ImageIO.read(imageURL);
File outputfile = new File("saved.png");
ImageIO.write(img, "png", outputfile);
```

But when i export the project to a jar file and try to run it via windows (7- 64 bit) command line, the following error appears:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Providercom.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName == null!
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(Unknow
n Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at SimpleQueueServiceSample.testOCR(SimpleQueueServiceSample.java:75)
        at SimpleQueueServiceSample.main(SimpleQueueServiceSample.java:69)
        ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName == null!
        at javax.imageio.spi.IIOServiceProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderWriterSpi.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi.<init>(CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi.java:80)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

I also using that imports:

```
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
```

Please, someone know the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `http://www.MY_IMAGE.jpg` -> 404.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: M8, this was just an example URL ;), u can use any image u want (jpg, png).

Comment: Why angry?! take this image:http://www.idautomation.com/ocr-a-and-ocr-b-fonts/new_sizes_ocr.png

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAI vendorname == null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051603/jai-vendorname-null)

Answer (score 1):

If you export using "Runnable JAR file" then Eclipse will add a custom `ClassLoader` and a custom `main` class into the jar file.

On the same time it seems you have installed some Image-IO extensions into the JDK - something providing the class `CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi`. On my system (Ubuntu, JDK 1.7) there is no such class but `JPEGImageReaderSpi`. The `CLib` part makes me think, that you have installed a native library doing the JPEG reading.

These two parts together seem to make the trouble. Solution - Try to export as a simple jar, start by hand providing the classpath on the commandline. If that works, provide a shell wrapper providing the classpath for easier use.

**EDIT** Googling around I have found an article with exactly that problem:

https://www.java.net//node/695773

Comment: Thanks, it's really the problem, and when i generate a simple jar it works, but how:
"start by hand providing the classpath on the commandline"

Comment: I mean on the commandline something like `java -classpath SOMETHING_SUITABLE my.qualified.classname.Here`

Answer (score 1):

I guess I can provide another solution as to this question since I got this error a few days ago and finally solve it.

1. You can check this article first, here explained the reason: [Exception when trying to save images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345769/exception-when-trying-to-save-images)
   ==> To sum up, the required META-INF the jar need to use is missing, so it can't find the "vender-Name" in the MANIFEST.MF.
2. As a result, I use MAVEN to generate the required runnable jar instead of using Eclipse to generate it. How? You can write a pom.xml to achieve it and remember to use "maven-assembly-plugin" to generate the required MANIFEST.MF in the jar file. This is the key step. And I can also give you a sample(pom.xml) for it:

   ```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
   <groupId>xxxProject</groupId>
   <artifactId>xxxProject</artifactId>
   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
   <repositories>
       <repository>
           <id>oss.sonatype.org</id>
           <name>Sonatype Snapshot Repository</name>
           <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
           <releases>
               <enabled>false</enabled>
           </releases>
           <snapshots>
               <enabled>true</enabled>
           </snapshots>
       </repository>
   </repositories>
   <build>
       <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
       <resources>
           <resource>
               <directory>src</directory>
               <excludes>
                   <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
               </excludes>
           </resource>
       </resources>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.3</version>
               <configuration>
                   <source>1.8</source>
                   <target>1.8</target>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
               <configuration>
                   <descriptorRefs>
                       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                   </descriptorRefs>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                           <mainClass>com.demo.Main</mainClass>
                           <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                           <addDefaultSpecificationEntries>true</addDefaultSpecificationEntries>
                       </manifest>
                       <manifestEntries>
                           <Specification-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Specification-Vendor>
                           <Implementation-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Implementation-Vendor>
                       </manifestEntries>
                   </archive>
               </configuration>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <id>create-my-bundle</id>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>single</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   <dependencies>
       <dependency>
           <groupId>org.json</groupId>
           <artifactId>json</artifactId>
           <version>20151123</version>
       </dependency>
   </dependencies>
   ```

So, the most important part is:

```
<manifestEntries>
                        <Specification-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Specification-Vendor>
                        <Implementation-Vendor>Sun Microsystems, Inc.</Implementation-Vendor>
                    </manifestEntries>
```

That means maven will add the required META-INFO for you in the jar so that you can solve this issue.

That's it. Hope these info can help you. =)