# JAI vendorname == null (standard solution doesn't work)

Tags: java, eclipse, javax.imageio, jai

While using `ImageIO` I get this `java.util.ServiceConfigurationError`:

```
javax.imageio.spi.ImageInputStreamSpi: Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.stream.ChannelImageInputStreamSpi could not be instantiated caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName == null!.
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051603/jai-vendorname-null) to solve my problem, but it didn't help. My `MANIFEST.MF` in `jai_imageio.jar` contains all required info:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.6.2
Created-By: 1.4.2_12-b03 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Specification-Title: Java Advanced Imaging Image I/O ToolsSun Microsystems, Inc.
Implementation-Title: com.sun.media.imageio
Implementation-Version: 1.1
Specification-Version: 1.1
Implementation-Vendor: Sun Microsystems, Inc.
Extension-Name: com.sun.media.imageio
Sealed: true
```

Important - this error occures only when I run my program as exported runnable jar file without Eclipse. When I run with Eclipse everything works fine.

Comment: How do you build your runnable JAR? Do you build a single JAR containing *all* your classes and dependencies, like JAI etc, or just your own code?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495555/java-export-to-jar-i-o-problems

Answer (score 1):

I know it's old and has been asked many times on SO, but I had the same problem and the standard solution didn't work for me either, so I picked this one to share my solution. I have all the attributes in my manifest (including `Specification-Vendor`, which is missing in the OP's snippet) but the Hadoop RunJar class on AWS EMR clusters seems to unpack the jar and thus the manifest is ignored (I didn't really investigate that in more depth). 
I ended up with a solution using reflection:

```
public static void tweakPackageUtil (Class<?> packageUtilClass, String vendor, String version, String specTitle) throws NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException
{
    Field vendorField = packageUtilClass.getDeclaredField("vendor");
    vendorField.setAccessible(true);
    vendorField.set(null, vendor);

    Field versionField = packageUtilClass.getDeclaredField("version");
    versionField.setAccessible(true);
    versionField.set(null, version);

    Field specTitleField = packageUtilClass.getDeclaredField("specTitle");
    specTitleField.setAccessible(true);
    specTitleField.set(null, specTitle);
}
```

and called this method for all `PackageUtil` classes - in my case:

```
com.sun.media.imageioimpl.common.PackageUtil.class,
io.scif.media.imageioimpl.common.PackageUtil.class,                                                                            
com.github.jaiimageio.impl.common.PackageUtil.class
```

It doesn't really matter what exact values for `vendor`, `version` and `specType` are used as long as they are not `null`.