# using JAI Imageio exception because of (vendorname = null) while running executable jar, working fine in eclipse

Tags: executable-jar, jai

> using JAIImageio library, getting exception because of (vendorname =
>   null) while running executable jar, working fine in eclipse. tried all
>   the available links but not working

http://www.java.net/node/677168
http://www.java.net/node/695773

> getting these exceptions
>
> Caused by: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi : Provider
>   com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi could n
>   ot be instantiated: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName ==
>   null!
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
>           at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(Unknow
>   n Source)
>           at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.imageio.ImageIO.(Unknown Source)
>           at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(ImageIOHelper.j
>   ava:287)
>           at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.mergeTiff(ImageIOHelper.java:34
>   7)
>           at net.sourceforge.vietocr.PdfUtilities.convertPdf2Tiff(PdfUtilities.jav
>   a:43)
>           at net.sourceforge.vietocr.ImageIOHelper.getIIOImageList(ImageIOHelper.j
>   ava:274)
>           at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:165)
>           at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:150)
>           at com.hs.TessractExample.main(TessractExample.java:37)
>           ... 5 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName == null!
>           at javax.imageio.spi.IIOServiceProvider.(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderWriterSpi.(Unknown Source)
>           at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi.(
>   CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi.java:80)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>
> ```
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Sou
> ```
>
> rce)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>           ... 18 more

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495555/java-export-to-jar-i-o-problems

Comment: thanks for the response was helpful