# Java load TIFF with getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, inputstream, tiff, javax.imageio

I have a problem while loading a TIFF Image. 
I use `ImageIO.read(Test.class.getResourceAsStream(url))` to read an image, with a JPEG it works perfect, but with a TIFF image I get a `NullPointerException`. The JPEG image and TIFF image are in the same folder.

Edit: Stacktrace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 
    at de.test.test1.files.Konstantenbeleg.<init>(Konstantenbeleg.java:47) 
    at de.test.test1.files.Konstantenbeleg.<init>(Konstantenbeleg.java:72)
    at de.de.test.test1.worker.zv.WorkerZVDZService. sendFiles(WorkerZVDZService.java:119)
    at de.de.test.test1.worker.zv.WorkerZV.workJob(WorkerZV.java:73)
    at de.de.test.test1.listener.action.scan. MyScanJobListener.finalzeScan(MyScanJobListener.java:65)
    at de.de.test.test1.listener.action.scan. MyScanJobListener.scanJobNoMoreEvents(MyScanJobListener.java:156)
    at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.core.function.ScanJobImpl.fire(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.core.function.ScanJobImpl.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.core.function.ScanJobImpl$JobEventHandler.exec(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.core.manager.EventRunner$Dispatcher.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at jp.co.ricoh.dsdk.core.manager.EventRunner$Dispatcher.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Where is your stack trace? Are you getting the `NullPointerException` from the `ImageIO.read()` invocation, or some other line? Most likely @ReneM is correct, you need to install a TIFF `ImageReader` plugin, but there's not enough detail in the question to say for sure.

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the Java Docs of JRE:

> Returns a BufferedImage as the result of decoding a supplied
>   InputStream with an ImageReader chosen automatically from among those
>   currently registered. The InputStream is wrapped in an
>   ImageInputStream. If no registered ImageReader claims to be able to
>   read the resulting stream, null is returned.

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read(java.io.InputStream)

This method will return null if there is no ImageReader registered for the desired format.

As I see there is no TIFF Image Reader included in standard JRE API. 
After some googling I found this: 
http://download.java.net/media/jai-imageio/javadoc/1.1/com/sun/media/imageio/plugins/tiff/package-summary.html

The educational answer of your question is:

Get an ImageReader Impl. which can decode TIFF Images. Register this ImageReader so the ImageIO.read method can determine this reader as the one for your TIFF image.

Comment: What you actually mean with register this ImageReader? I have the lib JAI in my project and the lib plugin imageio-tiff. The Nullpointer i get if i try to use toString() Methode.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17178591/how-to-add-tiff-imagereader-to-those-registered-in-grails/17186178#17186178