# JAI -javax.imageio.ImageIO exception while running exported jar

Tags: java, jar, javax.imageio, jai

My Eclipse installation doesn't have any issues when I'm running the project but if i exported the same as runnable `jar` file then I'm getting an exception as follows:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi: Provider com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi could not be instantiated
            at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.nextService(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
            at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(Unknown Source)
            at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.registerApplicationClasspathSpis(Unknown Source)
            at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at javax.imageio.spi.IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance(Unknown Source)
            at javax.imageio.ImageIO.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
            at emiratesid.ae.sample.MainFrame.displayPublicData(MainFrame.java:837)
            at emiratesid.ae.sample.MainFrame.loadPublicData(MainFrame.java:754)
            at emiratesid.ae.sample.MainFrame$PublicDataThread.run(MainFrame.java:1267)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: vendorName == null!
            at javax.imageio.spi.IIOServiceProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderWriterSpi.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at javax.imageio.spi.ImageReaderSpi.<init>(Unknown Source)
            at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.jpeg.CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi.<init>(CLibJPEGImageReaderSpi.java:80)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
            ... 11 more
    Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class javax.imageio.ImageIO
            at emiratesid.ae.sample.MainFrame.displayPublicData(MainFrame.java:837)
            at emiratesid.ae.sample.MainFrame.loadPublicData(MainFrame.java:754)
            at emiratesid.ae.sample.MainFrame$PublicDataThread.run(MainFrame.java:1267)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Did anyone gone through this kind of exception. Seeking help.

Comment: Which libraries are you using in your project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAI vendorname == null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051603/jai-vendorname-null)

Comment: PS: Disregard the accepted answer, and see the highest voted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18495658/1428606. Explains everything pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Could you compile the below class and run it as `java -cp your_runable.jar:. Check`.

```
public class Check {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(
            com.sun.media.imageioimpl.common.PackageUtil.getVendor()
        );
    }
}
```

The output should be similar to the one from running `java -cp jai_imageio-1.1.jar:. Check`

```
Sun Microsystems, Inc.
```